# Нет данных в боксплот matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

У меня есть дата сет с средними чеком по магазинам в недельной разбивке, и я хочу посмотреть плотность через боксплот.
На графике отображены все магазины, но по половине данных не показаны, хотя в таблице они есть.

Пробовала разделить данные, но появляется смещение ящиков относительно подписей.
Подскажите, в чем проблема?
Если строить диаграмму рассеяния, то по всем магазинам отображаются данные, но она не подходит[image: см скрин]

```
plt.figure(figsize=(20, 10))
check_box.boxplot()
plt.ylim(0,400)
plt.xticks(np.arange(len(check_box)), check_box['Название магазина'], rotation=90)
plt.show()
```

Comment: ну вот опять же, без данных трудно понять. попробуйте использовать boxplot от matplotlib (plt.boxplot), либо указать в `check_box.boxplot()` параметр `by` явным образом.